# Sudden Pay out issue

Tags: block-reward

Once the daemon was fully synced and the pruned block chain downloaded on to the computer, I have been receiving a payout of roughly 0.0002+ every 2 to 5 days, consistently since the mid of august of this year.
the last 10 days has no record of a payment.
Is this normal?
Running the monero wallet gui on the p2pool mini.
Thank you.